# Passing a form value to php from a JS function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am working on the following code and I am trying to pass the content of an input text called "stName" to the php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css">

<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
function connect()
{   
    $.ajax({
        url:'hostname/reply.php',
        headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        type:'POST',
        data:$('form').serializeArray(),
        //data:$(this),
        dataType:'JSON',
        error:function(jqXHR,text_status,strError){
            alert(strError);},
        timeout:60000,
        success:function(data){
            $("#result").html("");
                for(var i in data){
                $("#result").append("<li>"+data[i]+"</li>");                    
                }
            }
        });     
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center><b>My Students</b></center>
<center>
<form>
<input type="text" value="Joe" name ="stName" />
<input onclick="connect()" type="button" value="showStudents" />
</form>
</center>
<center><b>Results</b></center>
<ul data-role="listview" id="result"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And the simple php code is:

```
<?php    
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
    $message[] = $data; 
    print json_encode($message);
?>
```

The code that accesses the database has been stripped out. I just want to access the form value and it is not working. Any advice please?

Comment: data got to be a key value pair

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is no different to what browsers do when you send a form (via the action attribute):
It does a HTTP request to some URL. For POST requests, the default is to send the query string in the body of the request in form:

```
key1=value1&key2=value2
```

You may know this from URLs as the part after the ? character.

For parameter data of $.ajax function you pass exactly this query string. However you may also pass an object, which gets converted automatically to a query string. For example, your form data could be represented as this object:

```
{
  stName: "Joe"
}
```

And it would be converted by $.ajax to the query string and sent in the body of Ajax request:

```
stName=Joe
```

This query string would also be sent to your script, would you use the action attribute for the form element.

In your PHP script, you can then access the parameters through the $_POST array, with the keys in the query string being the keys in the $_POST array. For example, to print out stName parameter:

```
echo $_POST["stName"];
```

All this doesn't have much to do with JSON. In fact, you don't need JSON in order to use Ajax. Sending query strings is sufficient for many cases. Your code could be rephrased like this:

```
function connect()
{   
    $.ajax({
        url:'hostname/reply.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: {
          stName: $('#name-input').val() // Give the input an id
        },
        error:function(jqXHR,text_status,strError){
            alert(strError);},
        timeout:60000,
        success:function(data){
            // JSON is decoded for you if Content-Type of response is set appropriately.
        });     
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ali for all the clarifications. I am trying this: data: { stName: "Joe" }, in the function and $message[] = $_POST["stName"];
print json_encode($message); in the php code. I am expecting to get "Joe" but returns null. Any comment please?

Comment: PHP's `json_encode` is broken in the regard that it returns null on errors, but null is also a valid JSON value. Please check for errors with `json_last_error` or `json_last_error_msg` (see docs on php.net). You can also check what is sent to the server with the tools provided by the browser (in Firefox Ctrl+Shift+Q).

Comment: Hi Ali,I am getting this message: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". I have no clue what went wrong. Any suggestions?